# can not read png file with libpng

Tags: c, libpng

I am new to libpng and the documentation is really confusing for me.
Below is my code which is not working and I do not see the reason why.
Can someone point me to right direction? or suggest different ( "easier" ) library?

how I understand libpng:

1. open the file with `fopen` in `rb` mode
2. create `png_structp` with `png_create_read_struct`
3. create `png_infop` with `png_create_info_struct`
4. allocate space
5. read data

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <png.h>

   int main( int argc, char **argv )
   {
       int x, y;
       int height, width;

       png_structp png_ptr;
       png_infop info_ptr;

       png_bytep *row_pointers;

       FILE *fp = fopen( "test.png", "rb");
       {
           if (!fp)
               printf("File could not be opened for reading");

           png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);

           info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);

           png_read_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);
           width = png_get_image_width(png_ptr, info_ptr);
           height = png_get_image_height(png_ptr, info_ptr);

           row_pointers = (png_bytep*) malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * height);
           for (y=0; y<height; y++)
               row_pointers[y] = (png_byte*)malloc(png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr,info_ptr));

           png_read_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);

           fclose(fp);
       }

       for (y=0; y<height; y++) 
       {
           png_byte *row = row_pointers[y];
           for (x=0; x<width; x++) 
           {
               png_byte* ptr = &(row[x*4]);
               printf("Pixel at position [ %d - %d ] has RGBA values: %d - %d - %d - %d\n", x, y, ptr[0], ptr[1], ptr[2], ptr[3]);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: `png_create_read_struct` fail. compilator do not write any errors it just do nothing

Comment: How so? You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: i use `if (!png_ptr) printf("png_create_read_struct failed");` to see what is wrong.

Comment: Apparently it cannot allocate the structure. What compiler/etc are you using?

Comment: VS 2008 express, can it be caused by wrong include libpng files to compilator? I hade a litle trouble with it.

Answer (score 4):

I similarly had failure in **png_create_read_struct**. It is difficult to debug without further info (in my case, stderr goes nowhere), but fortunately you can provide your own error and warning functions:

```
void user_error_fn(png_structp png_ptr, png_const_charp error_msg);
void user_warning_fn(png_structp png_ptr, png_const_charp warning_msg);
```

Using this, libpng printed helpful errors stating that the application was using a different version of the header than the libpng found at runtime. Mystery solved.

So while individual issues may differ, using libpng's error reporting should provide insight.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, there is no information passed to libpng about where/how to read image chunk. Use:

...
png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);
png_read_info..

Comment: He still needs `png_ptr` to be non-null to use `png_init_io`.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: you are right but he'll face that problem soon :-)